# How to register RPC service as servlet in web.xml

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

I have created RPC service in my existing application using the RPC tutorial mentioned on the page 
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html#services. I am still getting the 404 no service found exception. Here is what I have done.

1. Created the service interface on client side.

   ```
   @RemoteServiceRelativePath("searchportoutorder")
   public interface SearchPortOutOrderService extends RemoteService {
           List<SearchPortOutOrderModel> fetchMoreRecords();
   }
   ```
2. Created the asynce interface on client.

   ```
   public interface SearchPortOutOrderServiceAsync {

       void fetchMoreRecords(AsyncCallback<List<SearchPortOutOrderModel>> async);
   }
   ```
3. Create the service impl under package server.

   ```
   public class SearchPortOutOrderServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements SearchPortOutOrderService {
       List<SearchPortOutOrderModel> models = new ArrayList<SearchPortOutOrderModel>();

       private void initializeModel() {
               for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                       SearchPortOutOrderModel model = new SearchPortOutOrderModel();
                       model.setOrderId("1234-132131-12312-12312");
                       model.setCustomer("ashish testing");
                       model.setOrderDate("2014-12-25");
                       model.setLastUpdated("2014-02-15");
                       model.setStatus("Completed");
                       models.add(model);
               }
       }

       @Override public List<SearchPortOutOrderModel> fetchMoreRecords() {
               initializeModel();
               return models;
       }
   ```
4. Update the web.xml file to involve the servlet.

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>searchPortOutOrderService</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.inetwork.gwt.client.searchportoutorder.server.SearchPortOutOrderServiceImpl</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>searchPortOutOrderService</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/report/searchportoutorder</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

I am still getting 404 exception saying that the service is not found.Do I need to modified anything else in my code like .gwt.xml file.

Comment: Can you show your doGet() and or doPost() methods.

Comment: doGet() or doPost() of what ?

Comment: Isn't this a web application ?

Comment: yes but GWT does not mentioned to implement doGet or doPost

Comment: In most cases the url-pattern in Web.xml doesn't match the one in @RemoteServiceRelativePath

Answer (score 0):

if your gwt module name is not **report**

modify *.gwt.xml like this.

```
<module rename-to='report'>
```

or replace url-pattern in web.xml to your gwt-module-name.

Comment: I am sure about the module name is report but I need to check the url-pattern